# Load .txt data files to DataGridView

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a code to open point file and read the data files:

```
private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\Yamaha";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    using (var reader = File.OpenText(@filename))
                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            //Do fetch data and paste to gridview operation
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I stuck in the while loop.  I want the loop to go through the file and fetch all the data and paste it on the gridview.

My gridview is like:
[image]

My text file is like:

[image]

Comment: I see fixed spaces between each value in your text file, so you need to first extract file line by line (in the loop) then use string functions (e.g. you can repalce the fixed white spaces with a minus sign: - then split each row on minus sign to get individual values as simple string array elements, then create a GridViewRow object setting cells etc. You need more effort to make as the code u provided is at very initial level as per the problem

Comment: Do you know the method `string[] System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string path)`? See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Usually you don't paste data to datagridview but you set it's DataSource property.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not so big, it would be very simple using linq. You just need to read all lines parse each line and set the GridView's DataSource.

```
private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\Yamaha";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       try
       {
           string[] fileLines= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
           IEnumerable<string[]> splitedLines = fileLines.Select(c => c.Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
           var data = splitedLines.Select(c => new
           {
               Point = c[0],
               X = c[2],//c[1] would be "=" sign
               Y = c[3],
               Z = c[4],
               R = c[5],
               A = c[6],
               B = c[7],
               C = c[8]
           });
           dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Error: Something is not right. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this program nothing to do with database. So there's no need of data source right?please advise.

Comment: DataSource is not just about the database, this property gets or sets the data source that the DataGridView is displaying data for, and the data can be read from any kind of source, database, plain text file, xml and ....

Comment: Tq for advise,but i try this code and still not working..no error but nothing happen..any idea?

Comment: I updated the answer `dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToArray();
` it should work now.

Comment: still got error. "Index was outside bounds array". any idea please?

Comment: It may be caused by an empty line(at beginning or at the end of the file), or a line with different formatting you should add checks for this situations.